# Store , Show and Delete items in session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

I am trying to save registered product id session in array, and delete any of the product from the session array using the id but it only save one and replace it when i post new product. I have searched online but still couldn't get what will help me fix this.

```
<?php 
session_start();
//Saving session
if(!empty($_SESSION["items"])){
$_SESSION["items"] = array();
$_SESSION["items"][] = $_POST['product_id'];
}else{
$_SESSION["items"] = $_POST['product_id'];
}

//Get one session
echo $_SESSION["items"][$_POST['product_id']];

//Delete one session
unset($_SESSION["items"][$_POST['product_id']]);
?>
```

Example 2

```
<?php 
session_start();
$product_id = '300';
$itemID = 'C';
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
  $_SESSION['items'] = array();
  $_SESSION['items'][$itemID] = array('code' => $product_id);
}else{
    $_SESSION["items"][$itemID][] = $product_id;
}
echo $_SESSION["items"]['A']['code']; // This is not showing anything
var_dump($_SESSION["items"]); // below array is what i get
?>

array(3) { ["A"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "100" } ["B"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "200" } ["C"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "300" } }
```

Please can anyone assist me on how i can get this right

Comment: @mickmackusa i have new one that is saving and when print var_dump it shows the array of items but it can't when i need to get one item. Please can i update my question again so you look it it?

Comment: @mickmackusa please see the current version of my question

Comment: @mickmackusa i have fixed it now is working, the problem is from  `$_SESSION["items"][$itemID][]` but i still found another problem. When i try to echo `$_SESSION["items"]['C']['code']` it will print only 3 instead of 300

Comment: @mickmackusa http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96b23c054ec5269f462a8fbfb29c2b7a9bba8be2

Comment: @mickmackusa Like this `array ( 'A' => array ( 'code' => '100'), 'B' => array ( 'code' => '200', ), 'C' => array ( 'code' => '300', ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Code:

```
$product_id = '300';
$itemID = 'C';
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    $_SESSION['items']=[];
}
$_SESSION["items"][$itemID]['code']=$product_id;
var_export($_SESSION["items"]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'C' => 
  array (
    'code' => '300',
  ),
)
```

Every added `$product_id` will have a key of `code`.  That subarray will be inside of `$itemID` which will be inside of `items` which will be inside of `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no items in your session, you save it in the $_SESSION['items']. While when there is one item in it, you create a new array to save it, and drop the old value, and save the new item in the new array.

So there is only one item or array with one item or none item in your session.

Just replace your if eles statement to this, to avoid of the warning you can add `@` at the beging of the assignment, or test if its set before the assignment.

```
$_SESSION["items"][] = $_POST['product_id'];
```

Comment: Please i updated my question with another code that i tried using but still not working